# Make a button of any language which has your user and pass embedded to make easy log in for particular website

Tags: button, authentication, embed

I have 'several accounts' in a website which I always log in everyday. Now, I want it to be easy by just clicking buttons in order to log in a particular account. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any experience using jQuery for DOM manipulation, it's fairly easy to do what you're asking using [tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) / [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

Basically you'd add a script that would trigger only on a particular domain. That script would import jQuery (just for ease of use) and append N buttons to the DOM. Using jQuery again, those buttons would have a given behavior that, in your case, fill the login and password input fields and submit the info.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Multilogin
// @version    0.1
// @match      http://website.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('body').prepend('<button id="my1stID" data-login="brian1" data-password="asdfg" value="my1stID"/>');

    jQuery('body').prepend('<button id="mi2ndID" data-login="brian2" data-password="asdfg2" value="my2ndID"/>');

    jQuery('body').prepen('<button id="mi3rdID"...');

    jQuery(document).on('click','my1stID',function() {
        var login=jQuery(this).data('login');
        var password=jQuery(this).data('password');
        jQuery('#login_input').val(login);
        jQuery('#password_input').val(password);
        jQuery('#submit').click();
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click','mi2ndID',function() {
        ....
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click','mi3rdID',function() {
        ....
    });
});
```

Take into consideration that storing your passwords in a script is very insecure and with my answer I'm giving you enough rope to hang yourself.